Does the [coinbase] tag refer to the business or coinbase transactions?
The [coinbase] tag does not have a description yet, however seems to currently be used for both the business and in the meaning of 'coinbase' transaction.
Does the [coinbase] tag refer to the business or coinbase transactions?

On second thought, I think that was not the best solution then.
I would like to propose the following:

The tag coinbase.com should refer to the company Coinbase.
Examples:
How did Coinbase monitor BTC transactions?
How do I reset my TFA token in Coinbase?
The tag coinbase-transaction should refer to Coinbase Transactions.
Examples:
Who generates the coinbase transaction?
Must a Block contain a coinbase transaction?
The tag mining-reward should cover more general questions about mining rewards.
Example:
Why is the reward decreasing while the difficulty of mining is increasing?
The tag coinbase should be merged into coinbase.com, as it's the more common usage of Coinbase.

Any thoughts?

Just looked through the questions tagged with [tag:coinbase], then merged the respective old tags into the new tags.

The [coinbase] tag could refer to the business and the tags description would be updated accordingly. The description should clarify that questions concerning 'coinbase transactions' are tagged with [reward].
